# Botpress conversation ender

Tags: bots, robot, botpress

I'm trying to set up a conversation ender for my botpress bot. So anytime the user would type end, a workflow should be triggered that will end the conversation.

I've tried to add intents, triggers... but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.